# Making abstract methods available to sub classes

Tags: c#, oop

I want to be able to use the method `RaiseMessage` that exists on the Abstract Class `AgentBase`, on other classes through the program.

```
public class MNyTestAgent: AgentBase
{
   RaiseMessage("hey", "hey")

   var a = new Foo();
}

public class Foo
{
   public Foo()
   {
      RaiseMessage("","") -<< how do i use it here 
   }
}
```

Comment: _"how do i use it here "_ You don't. But that has nothing to do with inheritance. You _could_ pass an Action (i.e.delegate) to Foo and make that Action said RaiseMessage. Or Foo could have an event for which MNyTestAgent could register and the handler would then call the method...

Comment: It would really help if your code a) came close to compiling and b) represented anything like what your narrative describes. There are no abstract classes here, but what we do have is statements appearing directly inside a class, not inside a member.

Comment: declare `RaiseMessage(string, string)` as virtual in `AgentBase`. a) Shouldn't `Foo`  class be `AgentBase`? Looks to my that you got your class names wrong in your code. And b) I see no abstract class declared

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code isn't valid C#.

Second of all, if you want to have a method accessible everywhere else, you probably want a `public static`. To implement a `public static` method you need to first reconsider your life choices, as doing so in an `Agent` class looks like bad design and a violation of OOP principles. If you still decide that you need it, something like this should work:

```
public abstract class AgentBase
{
   public static RaiseMessage(string title, string message)
   {
        // Implementation.
   }
}

public class MNyTestAgent: AgentBase
{
    public MNyTestAgent()
    {
        AgentBase.RaiseMessage("hey", "hey");
    }

}

public class Foo
{
   public Foo()
   {
      AgentBase.RaiseMessage("hey", "hey");
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Could maybe this help?

```
public class MNyTestAgent: AgentBase
{
   RaiseMessage('hey', 'hey')

   var a = new Foo(this);
}

public class Foo
{
   public Foo()
   {

   }

   public Foo(AgentBase base)
   {
      base.RaiseMessage('','') -<< how do i use it here 
   }
}
```

Comment: This does not even compile!